# Object has many objects has many objects in active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

Banging my head against the wall for these 2 days to figure out how to display object has many objects has many objects in active_model_serializers. Here is my serializers :

**Section** serializer :

```
class SectionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :title, :description

   has_many :questions, foreign_key: 'section_id', class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

And below is my **Comment** serializer

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body

  belongs_to :section

  has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 'question_id'
  belongs_to :question, class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

basically I want to achieve **Section** has_many **questions**, and **Question** has_many **replies**, but both **Question** and **Reply** are same model, that's **Comment** model.

The question is how to include **replies** when I fetch all Sections. For now I got this JSON :

```
  {
     "id": 1,
     "title": "section 1",
     "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
     "questions": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "body": "question 1"
         }
      ]
   }
```

As we can see there is no Replies in questions array and I need that JSON something like this from serializer.

```
   {
     "id": 1,
     "title": "section 1",
     "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
     "questions": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "body": "question 1",
            "replies" : [
                {
                   "id": 2,
                   "body": "reply 1 for question 1"
                },
                {
                   "id": 3,
                   "body": "reply 2 for question 1"
                }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which serializer you'd like to use for nested resources. A serializer can be applied to whatever model. You have to take care you're applying the right serializer to the right object in your controller, that's all.

```
class SectionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :title, :description
   has_many :questions, foreign_key: 'section_id', class_name: 'Comment', serializer: CommentSerializer, embed: :object
end

class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body
  has_many :replies, ..., embed: :object, serializer: ReplySerializer
end

class ReplySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body
end
```